# В чём разница между * и [] при объявлении массива?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

В функции strcpy элементы одного массива копируются в другой. Проблема в том, что при инициализации массивов в main при помощи указателя выдает segmentation fault

```
#include<unistd.h>
char    *strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;

    while (src[i])
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a = "abc";
    char *b = "def";
    char *c;
    c = strcpy(a, b);
    while(*c)
    {
        write(1, c, 1);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Но если задавать массивы при помощи [], все работает (выводит def).

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b[] = "def";
    char *c;
    c = strcpy(a, b);
    while(*c)
    {
        write(1, c, 1);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Почему? Как реализовать не используя "[]"?

Comment: Запись `char *a;` объявляет указатель, а не массив. Причем ему можно присваивать только указатель на изменяемый(е) объект(ы).

Comment: @user7860670 но ведь при записи char a[], a является частным случаем указателя на массив (его первый элемент). Или я не прав? И если это так, то непонятно в чем отличие...

Comment: массив может "притворятся" указателем на начало, даже более, очень часто, указатель и массив ведут себя очень похоже. Но это все таки разные вещи. Любой современный компилятор не будет компилировать конструкцию `char *a = "abc";`, а вот 'const char *a = "abc";` - будет. Правда строку не поменять

Comment: При объявлении *переменной* запись `char a[]` служит для объявления массива с длиной, выводимой из инициализатора. А при объявлении аргумента функции это будет указатель (собственно и в этом случае следует явно использовать указатель). `char a[] = "abc";` получается массив из 4 элементов, который инициализируется строкой из литерала.

Comment: @user7860670 Т.е. это на самом деле `char a[4] = "abc";` получается?

Comment: именнно так ...

Comment: @user7860670 Ну т.е., грубо говоря, мы не можем работать с этим указателем (*a), потому что непонятно на какой участок памяти он указывает? И отсюда идет seg fault? Если да, то... возникает другой вопрос: а почему мы задаем массив с динамической памятью через, например, `char *a = (char *) malloc(6*sizeof(char)); `? Или тут, выделяя память, мы задаем конкретный участок? Или я вообще все неправильно понял?)

Comment: Этот указатель указывает на участок памяти, который нельзя изменять, так как в нем хранится строковый литерал.

Comment: @KoVadim, gcc 7.5.0 уже совсем старый? Он спокойно (даже с -std=c11 и -Wall) компилирует `char *a = "abc";`

Comment: код то компилируется. и даже иногда работать будет. Но вот только ругается. сильно.

Comment: @avp Конечно компилирует если соотв. флаги не выставлять (`-Wwrite-strings -Werror`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ребята, не надо наводить тень на ясный день. :-) Версия компилятора тут абсолютно не причём. Просто думаем, что происходит. Итак объявляется **указатель** :

```
char *a = "abc";
```

А куда указывает этот указатель? На **константу**. А можно ли менять значение **константы** вот так:

```
dest[i] = src[i]; // dest[i] указывает на константу!!
```

Разумеется - нет! Иначе бы начали писать такие вот штуки:

```
int *iptr; 
iptr = &2; 
*iptr = 3;
printf("%d\n", *iptr);
```

Во что бы тогда превратилось программирование на С ?! А вот запись

char a[] = "abc";

Означает нечто совсем иное: **выделяется** память размером 4 байта, в эту память копируется (!) значение символьной константы "abc" и указателю *a* присваивается значение адреса первого элемента этого выделенного участка памяти. Поэтому операция

```
dest[i] = src[i]; // dest[i] указывает на переменную!!
```

вполне допустима.

Comment: Только беда в том, что в C это теоретически разрешено, насколько я помню. В С++ — нет. VC++ компилирует в режиме C без замечаний, например.

Comment: @Harry -"в C это теоретически разрешено" 
- Что "это"? Разрешено присваивать константе? Можно ссылочку на первоисточник, где про это написано?

Comment: Я не настаиваю, написал — насколько помню. Был бы под рукой источник — я бы писал в иной тональности :). Но компилятор VC++ в режиме С++ это скомпилировать не дает, а в режиме С — запросто. А разрешено — `char* a = "abc";`